# Header files repeatedly used in different header files in my static library

Tags: c++, winsock, static-libraries, header-files

Since I got multiple classes and utility-functions I reuse on a regular basis, I started to create a static library for those parts.

Until now, most of those header files with class and function declarations #include the same `"global" header file` which itself `#includes` other header files (like `<string>` `<windows.h>` etc.).

As for me, It feels annoying to force a user to include more than one header file when only "actively" using the one which got the classes.

So I vanquished the global header file and included all the necessary headers into my own headers.

This worked in some way, but I encountered some problems regarding `Winsock`:

You need to #define `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` and ensure that the user won´t `#include <windows.h>` before those headers of mine, or multiple redefinitions will occur :/.

That´s why I wanted to ask You how You would do this? Or what approches You can think of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you only have the option of defining a general header file that all other header files include and that defines WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN.

Otherwise you could instruct the user to include such definition in his own files, but his would be error prone.

As to inclusion of `<windows.h>` I think that it will not be included multiple times, since it has "include guards".

Comment: but then i have to "ship" all the header files.

The only other option left, that I see is mergin the headers.
hmmm

What i also thought about was putting a header guard around the windows.h and the winsock files

Comment: most libraries come with an executable and a directory containing all the header files, so I would not worry about this.. anyway, you can choose... :-)